# variable does not store value while running script from root (unix)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Output variable does not store value of "pbrun tsm_support.ksh -c $i" command while running this script though root.

```
 #!/bin/bash
set -x

for i in `cat /home/unixlist.txt`

do
output=$(pbrun tsm_support.ksh -c $i)
echo $output >> /home/file.txt
if echo "$output" | grep -i "OPTION01"  ;
then
echo successfull-- $i===$output
```

When I run this script from local user id it runs perfectly file and prints the output,

```
Error-- DBSSS0006=== Starting checkfix script.....DBSSS0006:B:SunOS:1:1:2:0:Z
Error-- DBSSS0005=== Starting checkfix script.....DBSSS0005:B:SunOS:1:1:2:0:Z
```

but when I run this script from root it does not take the value of output variable. It does not take value of $output.

```
  Error-- DBSSS0006===
  Error-- DBSSS0005===
```

I do not have root permissions, I can just edit crontab file and put my entry over there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the environment variables set in crontab versus the ones set  on your command line.
They are not the same.

To see what you have to change:
Put this in you crontab:

```
* * * * * set > /tmp/crontab.txt
```

Save it, wait for 2 -3 minuite for it to run, then remove the crontab change.

Next:

```
set > /tmp/myenv.txt
diff /tmp/myenv.txt /tmp/crontab.txt
```

will show you the differences.  Make some changes to your crontab script so it has (probably) the PATH variable and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable changes you need.  You do not have to change every environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution, I changed the path of my crontab script to /usr/bin/ksh, but still it is not working. does not see any LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is assuming powerbroker has the same environment variables when accessed in the batch mode as it is from the interactive terminal mode.

Even though it is impossible to say what deficiency exists there without seeing the actual tsm_support.ksh script contents, I can bet, there are assumptions made as in LD_LIBRARY_PATH will be the same everywhere and every time.

Try editing the script and putting the line

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/wherever/it/needs/to/point/to`

before doing anything else. Of course, this is valid if it is your only problem. I have worked with powerbroker 2 years in the past. It is not as trivial as one might expect from such a product. If in doubt, contact the Beyond Trust's (formerly Symark) tech support. Since you are licensing the product, you must be entitled to tech support. They can tell you what you are exactly missing.

Comment: Thanks Mel for going beyond to provide a solution for this issue, might be the issue is with power broker and since I don't know how this command works with root I will have to check that.